# Download subtitles with nautilus

Tags: nautilus

How to add "download subtitles" option (for example with Qnapi app) to nautilus context menu ? In any other file manager ther's no problem with that but in nautilus there's no qnapi option when I want to choose from another apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Nautilus scripts like this: https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1007672/

The installation and what you need to get this done is well explained there.

**Installation:**
Quick installation as a nautilus script, under GNOME 3 desktop environment:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/emericg/OpenSubtitlesDownload.git
$ mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/
$ cp OpenSubtitlesDownload/OpenSubtitlesDownload.py ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/OpenSubtitlesDownload.py
$ chmod u+x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/OpenSubtitlesDownload.py
```

... then you can only do a right click on any foreign movie you want to and use the script.

you can also check the settings of the script here: https://github.com/emericg/OpenSubtitlesDownload/wiki/Adjust-settings