# How to add entries in the right-click menu of a file manager?

Tags: nautilus, editing

How would I add an entry to the right-click menu of `Nautilus`, `PCmanFM`, or `Dolphin` without using scripts as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678358/download-subtitles-with-nautilus)?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is your desktop environment? Have you tried to install script manager for Nautilus (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/nautilus-script-manager) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options besides nautilus scripts that once existed are listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/21956/558158). Currently, as of Ubuntu 21.10 and Nautilus 40.2, your options are limited to [nautilus scripts](https://askubuntu.com/a/21956/558158) and [python3-nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/a/301205/558158).

Python nautilus extensions are most "integrated". To create your own extensions, some Python skills are required.